# Kernel crashing, trying to run a single convolution layer over 1 image

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am using the MNIST data and loading a single image for a cnn, I wanted to see how the image looks like after a single layer. I have gone through the documentation to see if there were any errors with my inputs or how I am consolidating the data. Is the code wrong by any means or is it just my computer ?

```
filtersw = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[5, 5, 1, 1], mean=0.5, stddev=0.01))
filtersb = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(1))
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, filtersw, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID') + filtersb
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
afterimage = sess.run(conv, feed_dict={x : X_train[0:1]})
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also you can edit your question to fix the indentation.

Comment: I am not getting any error but I observed the resources getting used. The ram fills up from 50% to 85% and then the kernel crashes and restarts. I have 8gigs of ram and as much as I can tell, the code shouldn't even use 10 mb for this step.

Comment: In that case more context could be helpful. Are you calling the above snippet in a loop by any chance?

Comment: No, its a single run. I wanted to see If I could mass produce filtered images, given I know the filter I am applying. But its breaking even for a single filter, so I am kinda at a road block. I have tried doing the same in a friends' computer which had tensorflow cpu and it worked fine. But I need to use a gpu for the speed. I think I should reinstall all my Cudnn to a lower version and my tensorflow too to a supported one. Most other functions work on the gpu for me, just can't seem to get functions in  nn/layers modules

Answer (score -2):

You need to call `tf.layers.conv2d` instead of `tf.nn.conv2d`. The two functions have the same name, but they perform different operations. `tf.layers.conv2d` creates a convolution layer in a CNN and `tf.nn.conv2d` performs convolution with a known filter or set of filters.

Comment: This is not correct. He uses `tf.nn.conv2d` correctly (passing to it the filter variable he creates beforehand).

Comment: He's trying to create a layer of a CNN, so he should call `tf.layers.conv2d`. You should only call `tf.nn.conv2d` if you know the exact values of the filter. In this case, he's created the filter using a variable, which means he don't know the filter's values.

Comment: I have defined my filter clearly, the variable 'filtersw'. I am using this filter in my convolution to compute the filtered image.